# State of JInternalFrame not kept

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe, maximize

I am dealing with a problem which relates to this bug I think: [DefaultDesktopManager does not handle InternalFrame state changes as expected.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4424247)

I have the following scenario:

My application consists of a `JFrame` which can have several `JInternalFrame`s. As an overview dialog I have a `JInternalFrame` which is maximized and shows a data table. The user can open a detail dialog for an entity in the table. The detail dialog is also a `JInternalFrame`.

1. Problem: Because the overview dialog was maximized the detail dialog is also maximized (what is not like expected).
2. Problem: When the detail dialog gets closed the overview dialog loses its maximized state. If the user clicks on any point in this dialog it gets back maximized. That's pretty ugly and confusing to the users. If I "un-maximize" the detail dialog before closing it the overview dialog also loses its maximied state and stays in this state.

It seems to me that the `JFrame` can only hold one global state for all its `JInternalFrame`s. I don't know how to create a simple workaround for this. Maybe someone had this trouble in the past and can guide me.

It is a bit hard to provide a SSCCE, maybe this is enough, I am showing the detail dialog by this:

```
DetailDialog detailDialog = new DetailDialog();
applicationFrame.getDesktopPane().add(detailDialog);
detailDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. I am using a controller class for the dialog and delegating the closing of the dialog to that class. In the controller I have to do some validations for example and then I call `dispose()` of the dialog. Now I am calling `setClosed(true)` instead which works. I think there where some fired events missing which are now fired.

Answer (score 1):

could be questions

1. hard to write something wise without seeing your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)
2. what output you'll expecting from [JInternalFrame[] getAllFrames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html#getAllFrames%28%29), is there some ???
3. what output you'll expecting from [Internal Frame Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/internalframelistener.html), is there some ???
4. did you place JInternalFrame to the JLayeredPane???

Comment: I added some code a SSCCE might be a bit too much code... I don't use 2. and 3. so I don't expect anything here (what should I?). 4. I am not using a `LayeredPane` I will have a look at this class if it could help me out.

Comment: from JInternalFrame[] getAllFrames() you can get all JInternalFrames and Internal Frame Listener talking about all implemented events, part of them (as I tried, maybe all) you can supply with PropertyChangeListener

Comment: I know what those are doing but my hope was that someone has an idea which prevents me from implementing what Swing should rather do.